# Bindings works only for one element

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `WPF Control` based on `DataTemplate`. Basically it displays an `Image` surrounded by a `Border`. In the code-behind I programmatically change the properties of the base class in order to change the size of the images. It works, through the bindings, but only for the images, not for borders.

### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageGallery.Control.ControlThumbnail"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageGallery.Control"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFDC9696">
                        <Border BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Background="Black" CornerRadius="10" ClipToBounds="True" BorderBrush="{Binding ImageBorder}">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" ClipToBounds="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### ImageClass

```
public class ImageClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Uri ImageUri { get; private set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    private int m_imageHeight;
    public int ImageHeight 
    { 
        get
        {  
            return m_imageHeight;
        } 
        set
        {
            m_imageHeight = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageHeight)));
        }
    }

    private int m_imageWidth;
    public int ImageWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return m_imageWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            m_imageWidth = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageWidth)));
        }
    }

    private Brush m_imageBorder;
    public Brush ImageBorder {
        get
        {
            return m_imageBorder;
        }
        set
        {
            m_imageBorder = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageBorder)));
        }
    }

    public ImageClass(string location)
    {
        if (File.Exists(location))
        {
            ImageUri = new Uri(location);
        }
        Label = location;
    }        
}
```

and here the relevant code of the `WPF Control`:

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageClass> Images
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ImageClass>)GetValue(ImagesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImagesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Images", typeof(ObservableCollection<ImageClass>), typeof(ControlThumbnail), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ControlThumbnail()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Images = new ObservableCollection<ImageClass>();
}

public void ResizeImages()
{
    foreach (var image in Images)
    {
        image.ImageHeight = newHeight;
        image.ImageWidth = newWidth;
    }
}
```

**The question is:**

The `Image` item in the `DataTemplate` is correctly resized due to the bindings (ImageWidth and ImageHeight) but the `Border` item doesn't. Why? The share the same bindings!

To be sure there isn't anything about the layouts I tried to explicitly set the Width and Height of the `Border` element. Its size is how set according to the values specified.

Comment: Too much code, but unclear in what your question.

Comment: I apologize, when I post less code I receive downvotes because I don't post enough code! The question is: why the `Image` is correctly resized (due to the bindings) while the `Border` doesn't? They have the same bindings.

Comment: Try to use `Thumb` instead `Border`. And set bindings only for it, and for `Image` try to use `Stretch=Fill` instead bindings to size(width, height).

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb(v=vs.110).aspx: "Represents a control that can be dragged by the user.". Anyway the IDE complains about the `Image` inside because "Thumb doesn't support direct content"

Comment: `Image` is inside `Border` which is 10 pixels bigger. How exactly *"doesn't works"* looks like? By default (if you don't specify size explicitly) border will autosize (assuming you are not stretching it), do you really have to set its size? You can do it via converter (or another property which returns 10+x size). Another thing: brush in viewmodel is bad (color and binding to `SolidColorBrush.Color` is ok) as well as naming members with `m_`.

Comment: As far as I understand, the margin is applied to the `Border` item. That is two `Border` items are separated by 20px. It "doesn't work" because the inside image is resized to the specified dimensions, while the outside border doesn't follow them. Forcing (in XAML) the Width and Height of `Border` leads to the desired size.

Comment: can you use https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ to check if the bindings are alright on the border?

Comment: Snoop is a great tool! Thank to it I discovered the problem: there was a swap in the code about Width and Height. Due to this it didn't work as expected!

Comment: so have you fixed it ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to answer because it wasn't related to the bindings indeed.

Comment: ok happy to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always to verify that your bindings are okay you can use the snoop wpf spy tool https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Also on VS 2015 are embedded tools to help you check the properties live.